# Using JQuery how can I change an image on hover slowly via fadeIn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout

CODE:

```
.icon_right {
    background-position: -235px -95px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
    height: 34px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 22px;
    z-index: 200;
}
.icon_base {
    background-image: url("/sprite.png");
}

<span class="icon_base icon_right"></span>
```

When icon_right is hovered I want to slowly changed the image using fadein/fadeout.  The images are in sprite.  How can i complete this using jquery?

I tried using this in the icon_right css:

```
         -webkit-transition: opacity .50s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .50s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity .50s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity .50s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity .50s ease-in-out;
```

UPDATE:

SOmething like this can work:

```
transition: 10s background-color;
```

But how do I do it for a background position?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @j08691 i updated question with what i tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="icon-holder" class="icon_base icon_right"></span>

$('#icon-holder').hover(function(){

  $('#icon-holder').removeClass('icon_right', 500);

});
```

Hope this helps you